# GitHub commit is not linked to my account

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit, git-push

All my github commits aren't linked to my account when I push from integrated terminal so I don't appear in any repository insights when it comes about statistics and stuff. Also the commit isn't linked to any author so I wouldn't be reachable

I tried everything found before on GitHub manuals but couldn't solve it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slZ5S.png)

Comment: What email did you set before you made the commits?

Comment: The same one used for github account

Comment: What integrated terminal are you referring to? You need to set your email in git (not github) to have the commits be associated with an email. `git config --global user.email "yourgithubemail@whatever.com"`, then make the commits, if you made the commits without that setting the commits won't be associated with an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made commits with an email that is not associated with your GitHub account. You have two choices:

1. Add the email to your account settings.
2. Use `git filter-branch` to change the email on your commits to the one that you already registered with GitHub.

Comment: It worked with git filter-branch, thanks. 
But is there any chance that previous commits to be linked to the correct email?

Comment: @AlexMititelu Do you mean "future commits"? If so, you need to use `git config` to set the correct email and name.

Comment: No, from now it looks fine, the commits are correctly linked with the github account.
But I was wondering if it's possible to fix this also for the commits made in the past, to be linked with my github account.

Comment: @AlexMititelu If you used `git filter-branch` correctly, it updated all past commits with a different email.

Comment: unfortunately the previous commits are still linked to an empty account: https://imgur.com/6SwVhRu

Comment: @AlexMititelu After you run `git filter-branch` on your local repo, you also need to run `git push -f`.

Comment: @AlexMititelu If you have already done that, you need to wait for about 24 hours to allow GitHub to update with the new information.

Comment: came back with with a 24h response. Well, my previous commits are still linked to that account that is not linked to github